# Skype Bot sending message (not a reply)

Tags: rest, skype, direct-line-botframework, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

Trying to create a Skype Bot, but I have a problem. Please, help me.
I use PHP so I use REST (not NodeJS or C# SDK).
The task: I have to send data from html form on my website to Skype (so I don’t have to reply to a message, but just send).
Well, I have successfully create a bot in Microsoft Bot Framework.
Then I have successfully received an access_token.
Then they say in docs that I have to send a POST to:

```
/v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages I have to send a request to `/v3/conversations` with JSON like that:

```
{
"bot": {
"id": "12345678",
"name": "bot's name"
},
"isGroup": false,
"members": [
{
"id": "1234abcd",
"name": "recipient's name"
}
],
"topicName": "News Alert"
}
```

But what is the "member's id and member's name"?

Comment: "I have to send data from html form on my website to Skype " - wouldn't it be easier to use e.g. https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the member ids of some members, add all those members in a group and add the bot, too, to the group and preferably send a message in the group, mentioning the bot. You will receive a json with a `conversationId`. With this `conversationId`, make a get request to `v3/conversations/{conversationId}/members` in order to receive the member-ids and member-names of the members in the group.

You can now proceed with these member-ids and member-names to start individual conversations with the members (which is illustrated in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47620574/8481074)).

Comment: Thank you! I guess your answer is correct, but I have already solved the problem. I just opened web version of skype and logged in as the member, I wanted to send messages to. Than I sent a message to myself (not to bot) and was able to see member's id in network of Google Chrome Inspector. The problem has gone, but I really don't understand why it is not easy to find member's ids...